# Pull out certain elements from two arrays into a separate array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filtering, discord.js

I want to compare two arrays by name and pull out of the second one(newLogins) only those with login value greater than the first one(oldLogins).

```
        const oldLogins = [
            { name: 'Anna', login: 0 },
            { name: 'Bob', login: 0 },
            { name: 'Sveta', login: 0 },
        ];

        const newLogins = [
            { name: 'Romeo', login: 1 },
            { name: 'Bob', login: 1 },
            { name: 'Sveta', login: 2 },
            { name: 'Jhon', login: 0 },
        ];
        // Thought it would work..
        const whoIsLogin = oldLogins.filter(function(item) {
            return newLogins[item.name].login > item.login;
        });

        console.log(whoIsLogin);
```

I want to get that conclusion:

```
        const whoIsLogin = [
            { name: 'Bob', login: 1 },
            { name: 'Sveta', login: 2 },
        ];
```

How can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just updated your logic with find method.

```js
const oldLogins = [
            { name: 'Anna', login: 0 },
            { name: 'Bob', login: 0 },
            { name: 'Sveta', login: 0 },
        ];

        const newLogins = [
            { name: 'Romeo', login: 1 },
            { name: 'Bob', login: 1 },
            { name: 'Sveta', login: 2 },
            { name: 'Jhon', login: 0 },
        ];
        // It should work now
        const whoIsLogin = newLogins.filter(function(item) {
            const oldLogin = oldLogins.find(oItem=>oItem.name===item.name)
            return oldLogin && oldLogin.login < item.login;
        });

        console.log(whoIsLogin);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and filter the second array.

```js
var oldLogins = [{ name: 'Anna', login: 0 }, { name: 'Bob', login: 0 }, { name: 'Sveta', login: 0 }],
    newLogins = [{ name: 'Romeo', login: 1 }, { name: 'Bob', login: 1 }, { name: 'Sveta', login: 2 }, { name: 'Jhon', login: 0 }],
    map = oldLogins.reduce((m, { name, login }) => m.set(name, login), new Map),
    result = newLogins.filter(({ name, login }) => login > map.get(name));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check this

```js
const oldlogins =[
  {name:"Anna",login:0},{name:"Bob",login:0},{name:"Sb",login:0}
]
const newlogins =[
  {name:"rom",login:1},{name:"Bob",login:1},{name:"Sb",login:2},{name:"Jhon",login:0}
]

let result =newlogins.filter((nitem,nindex)=>oldlogins.length-1>=nindex&&oldlogins[nindex].name===nitem.name&&oldlogins.length-1>=nindex&&oldlogins[nindex].login<nitem.login)

console.log(result)
```